# Получить объект по его string'овому названию

Tags: c#, visual-studio

У меня есть файл Resource.rexs, а также string'овое название файла.
Мне нужно каким-то образом получить этот файл из ресурсов.
Пример кода:

```
name_current_user = reader[0].ToString();
Type name = Type.GetType(reader[1].ToString()); // название файла
pictureBox1.Image = health.Properties.Resources.name; // doens't work
```

Comment: `if (name_current_user == "qucals") ...Properties.Resources.Qucals;`

Comment: Разумеется, так можно сделать. Но у меня там ни 5, ни 10 изображений. Неужели каждое так прописывать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Когда вы подключили ресурсы в своём приложении, Студия сгенерировала класс `Resources` в файле `Resources.Designer.cs`. Откройте его и посмотрите, как реализованы свойства.

Вы сами можете получить доступ к значениям по имени, используя `ResourceManager`:

```
var value = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(name);
```

И обязательно учитывайте культуру.