# Указатель на объект в функции

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Мне требуется много обращений к различным pictureBox и изменение в них изображений.
В данный момент делаю так:

```
pictureBox18.Image = Properties.Resources._12_3_normal;
```

Можно ли это каким-то образом делать функцией?

К примеру:

```
void Image(String img, String res)
    {
        img.Image = Properties.Resources.res; // Подменить картинку
    }
```

Но так не работает. Понимаю, что способ не верный и нужен указатель, но как это реализовать текущих знаний не хватает.

Comment: `String img`... `img.Image` Не смущает ничего?

Comment: Конечно смущает. Так не работает. Как сделать не знаю, поэтому и спрашиваю.

Comment: `void SetImage(PictureBox pictureBox, String res)` объекты прямо ссылкой и передаются, можете потом делать с их полями что хотите

Comment: @itehnotutby Ну вы просто подумайте логически, чем является `pictureBox18`? Для этого ведь достаточно просто навести на него мышку, будет ли он строкой (`string`)? Наверно нет, ну так почему вы вдруг решили написать `String img`? Не отключайте голову думая что это сложно ибо вы новичок, это не так, старайтесь самостоятельно изучить вопрос.

Comment: Судя по всему, надо такое? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17828774/get-resources-with-string

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/995734/184217